# set routine, but not by time instead by 20 min after start

Tags: actions-on-google

Not sure how to explain myself since I am totally new to this but I'd like to be able to tell Google to start my school day at any point in the morning (not a certain time) and from there be able to set a timer for each subject.

Example:

```
"ok google start school day"

google says "start math" and starts a 30 minute timer

after 30 minutes google asks "are you ready to switch subjects?"

users says "yes" or "no, give me 5 more minutes"

google starts another timer accordingly.
```

Is this possible to build? Totally new to this and don't have a lot of time to learn since I'm now currently homeschooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a routine in the Google Assistant settings that maps "Start school day" to "start a 30 minute timer" and other related actions. When the timer is finished, you won't be able to add an additional prompt.

However, you could at that point create a routine "Give me 5 more minutes" mapping to "start a 5 minute timer" and that would accomplish most of what you want.